# Calling /connect/userinfo return error "Unhandled exception: Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using IdentityServer4, AspnetCore 2.1 and angular 6 client

Everything is working fine except the call to the userinfo endpoint

Looking through my log I found the following lines that I thought could be pointers to how to deal with the error. So far I havent been sucessfully

```
StsServerIdentity>       Profile service returned the following claim 
types: sub name given_name family_name email role sub role role role 
preferred_username email email_verified
StsServerIdentity> crit: 
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0] 
StsServerIdentity>       Unhandled exception: Sequence contains more 
than one matching element
StsServerIdentity> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains 
more than one matching element
StsServerIdentity>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource] 
(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
```

looking forward to some guidance 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks you are using [a 3rd party solution](https://damienbod.com/2015/11/08/oauth2-implicit-flow-with-angular-and-asp-net-5-identity-server/) and it has it's own `IProfileService` implementation where sub claim is added twice and not distincted. You could either try to debug or distinct the sub claims (as that's a primary user identifier and must be unique), or try the original [quickstarts](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts).